# why "meteor npm install" is not working on gitpod workspace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, meteor, gitpod

I am new to gitpod.io, I am trying to open a meteor project on gitpod.io and when I type "**meteor npm install**", it's showing "**bash: meteor: command not found**", however, if I try "**npm install**" it's working fine.

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: is meteor installed on these gitpods?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `meteor` is not installed in the [default workspace Docker image](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/blob/master/full/Dockerfile).

You can run `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` in your workspace. You'll get a message like this:

```
Meteor 1.10.2 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Couldn't write the launcher script. Please either:

  (1) Run the following as root:
        cp "/home/gitpod/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.10.2/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
  (2) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (3) Rerun this command to try again.

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.
```

Since you don't have root rights, a script in `/usr/local/bin/` cannot installed by this way. However, you can still use meteor like this:

```sh
$ ~/.meteor/meteor
```

An alternative would be to add your own Dockerfile as described in the docs: https://www.gitpod.io/docs/config-docker/
By this, you can install `meteor` with root rights.